# Webpack cannot resolve absolute paths after upgrade from 4 to 5

Tags: webpack

I am trying (for what feels like the 100th time :)) to upgrade to Webpack 5.  Everything worked perfectly fine in Webpack 4, so I assume there is some setting of setting I have missed but cant seem to find it.

It is currently failing on absolute path recognition.  E.g. I have some links / images that specify absolute paths (for when deployed)

Some of the Webpack errors I am seeing

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/manifest.json' in 'C:\Projects\xyz\xyz\src'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/assets/images/logos/xyz-icon.png' in 'C:\Projects\xyz\xyz\src'
```

**Use in Index.html**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

**Use in a component** (Note I tried with and without the ~)

```
<img src="~/assets/images/logos/xyz-logo-white.png" class="group-logo" alt="Group Logo" />
```

I'm a bit lost on what to do, here are a few things I have tried with no success

Added a `file-loader` rule for images.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
},
```

Added a resolve path for my dist (target) folder

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        sourcePath,
        distPath
    ],
    fallback: { "util": false }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

file-loader and url-loader are deprecated from now you have to use assets/resources which is available in webpack 5
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/